# Is it possible to Compton scatter from delocalised pi-electrons in liquid scintillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, scattering

I am wondering if an incident gamma could compton scatter from the delocalised pi-electrons in an aromatic compound (e.g. liquid scintillator).

I understand that compton scattering is valid for free electrons, and is usually described in terms of the outer most atomic energy levels where incident photon energy >> binding energy. However, how about compton scattering from molecules, and particularly delocalised electrons in aromatics?

Furthermore, if it is possible, would the scintillator be excited and scintillate after a pi electron is removed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Most laboratory "Compton scattering" isn't from free electrons, but from bound electrons whose binding energies are small compared to the photon energy. Your pi electrons certainly qualify when illuminated with gamma rays. And yes, the scattered electron will excite the scintillator just as any other energetic electron does.

Delocalization within a molecule has no practical effect. Indeed, given how hard it is to focus gamma rays, in an experiment the incident photons will be more delocalized.